Does map_hash_max_size and map_hash_bucket_size influence uniformity of load distribution in consistent hashing(ip-hash) in nginx
Does the value set by map_hash_bucket_size and map_hash_max_size has any influence or relation on how uniform the load is distributed in nginx while using hash or ip-hash directives which inernally uses consistent hashing.
How does map_hash_bucket_size and map_hash_max_size different from variables-hash-bucket-size and variables-hash-max-size . Does these directive influence uniformity of load distribution.
There is very little documentation about these directives online.
